# Transform xml webservice data object to c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have problem to create data object for webService. I have wsdl file. I'm looking for method how to create c# object from below xml code. Is there any software which can do this automically?

```
<s:element name="ArrayOfProductRow">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PRODUCT" type="s:ProductRow" />
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ProductRow">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_INDEX" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_CODE" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_CATEGORY_INDEX" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_PRICE_NET" type="s:double" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_VAT_RATE" type="s:double" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_NAME" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_SHORT_DESCRIPTION" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_LONG_DESCRIPTION" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PRODUCT_ACTIVE" type="s:boolean" />
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Comment: I answered this, but then I realized that you might be asking for something that will write and compile classes for you from XSDs. Are you looking for deserialization, or code building?

Comment: I would like to build objects to pass it in webservice methods. I make request

Comment: Ohh, you want to build XML? That's different as well. Well, my answer below will still help you with that.

Comment: I haven't big experience with WebService but

Comment: I haven't big experience with WebService. I want build data object which I can put in methods in c# code. I think c# methods automatically build xml file to send it.

Comment: Have you looked into the answer I gave below?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [`System.Xml.Linq.XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx). It doesn't, at least as far as I know, do the (de)serialization for you, but it'll parse the XML and give you a very nice interface to deserialize it yourself. Not to mention, it's part of the .NET framework, which is always a nice little bonus as well.

```
var element = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("[your xml"]);
```

Then you can use the `XElement.Element` and `Elements` methods to navigate through. Just keep an eye on the namespaces, since they can be a little tricky if you aren't paying attention. But once you get the hang of it it's very adaptable.

**Edit:**

Or hold up, if you're looking for something to generate C# code for you, that's very different.

**Edit 2:**

You just made it clear that you're actually looking to *serialize* data, not deserialize it. My points here still stand. The XElement class is a great way to build dynamic, custom XML from your object to meet your spec. It's what I'd use. You can probably find some libraries out there that'll do it for you, but I tend to like a more hands-on approach. Particularly with something as intricate as talking to a web service, where a change by either one of you could cause huge problems if you tie your model directly to their request formats.

### Edit 3:**

I suppose it's also worth bringing up `DataContractSerializer`, although I tend to prefer against that as a general rule for the reasons I've said before. It's *easy*, but honestly in most cases I'm not sure how much easier it is than just building the XML manually, particularly given how easy it is to debug manual stuff and how hard it is to debug something that works virtually entirely off of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the namespace (the s:) and you're using VS2013, you can copy the xml, and use Edit->Paste Special->Paste XML as classes. I just did it, and got the following:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class element
{

    private elementComplexType complexTypeField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public elementComplexType complexType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.complexTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.complexTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class elementComplexType
{

    private elementComplexTypeElement[] sequenceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("element", IsNullable = false)]
    public elementComplexTypeElement[] sequence
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sequenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sequenceField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class elementComplexTypeElement
{

    private byte minOccursField;

    private string maxOccursField;

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte minOccurs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.minOccursField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.minOccursField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string maxOccurs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.maxOccursField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.maxOccursField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```